# STL Vector, Iterator and Insert (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a method to which a vector's iterator is passed.
In this method I'd like to add some elements into the vector, but I am not sure whether this is possible when having only the iterator

```
void GUIComponentText::AddAttributes(vector<GUIComponentAttribute*>::iterator begin, vector<GUIComponentAttribute*>::iterator end)
{
    for (vector<GUIComponentAttribute*>::iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    {
        GUIComponentAttribute &attrib = *(*i);

        // Here are the GUIComponentAttribute objects analyzed - if an object of a 
        // special kind appears, I would like to add some elements to the vector
    }
}
```

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll have to change the interface.  Given two iterators, 
there's no way to get back to the container to which they refer; so if
you want to modify the container, you'll have to pass a reference to it,
i.e.:

```
void GUIComponentText::AddAttributes(
        std::vector<GUIComponentAttribute*>& attributes )
{
    for ( std::vector<GUIComponentAttribute*>::iter = attributes.begin();
            iter != attributes.end();
            ++ iter )
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Having done that: insertion can invalidate iterators.  So it depends on
where you want to insert.  If you want to insert at the current
position:  `std::vector<>::insert` of a single element returns an
iterator to that element, which was inserted before your element, so you
can assign it to your iterator, adjust (if necessary), and continue:

```
iter = attributes.insert(iter, newAttribute);
++ iter;   //  Return to where we were...
```

If you're appending (`push_back`), the problem is a bit more complex;
you need to calculate the offset, then reconstruct the iterator:

```
size_t offset = iter - attributes.begin();
attributes.push_back( nweAttribute );
iter = attributes.begin() + offset;
```

In this case, it is probably simpler to iterate using a `size_t` and
`[]`, rather than an iterator.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, definitely does help.
(Just not in this case as the interface is unchangeable unfortunately)

Answer (score 4):

In the code you show, this is not possible. Especially because you should not add/remove elements to/from a vector while you iterate over it.

Comment: Thanks, I almost guessed that.
The purpose is in this case to split combined attributes into their parts to be able to keep the rest of the algorithm. So I'll try to find a work around

Answer (score 3):

This is a long standing design "issue" in the STL. Iterators do not allow the modification of the structure of the underlying sequence they are iterating over: ie you can modify (sometimes) the elements themselves, but you cannot add/remove elements. Though `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator` are a bit special in this regard... hum...

This is actually the cause of the `erase/remove` idiom:

```
vec.erase(std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), predicate), vec.end());
```

So, no, sorry, there is no way to actually modify the vector.

However, as exposed above, you can perfectly use the `remove_if` algorithm and simply return the new end of the valid range... or you can ask for the whole vector to begin with.

As noted by Björn, modifying a sequence structure while iterating over it is error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add elements into a vector whilst iterating over it. In addition, you most certainly cannot add one to a vector with just a pair of iterators- you'd need a pointer/reference to the whole vector object.

The best you could do is return a vector of new components to add by the the calling function.