# Iterating over a vector of maps, and inserting a copy if a condition is satisfied

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl

I'm new to stl in c++ and I want to iterate over a vector of maps. Then, if one of these maps satisfies a certain condition, I want to make a copy of this map an then insert the copy into the vector.

For example:

```
int main(){
   vector<map<string, int> > my_vector;
   map<string, int> my_map;
   my_map["zero"] = 0;
   my_vector.push_back(my_map);

   for(vector<map<string, int> >::iterator iter1 = my_vector.begin();
                                           iter1 != my_vector,end();
                                           iter1++){
      for(map<string, int>::iterator iter2 = (*iter1).begin();
                                     iter2 != (*iter1).end();
                                     iter2++){
         if(iter2->second == 0){
            // make a copy of the map (*iter1), make some changes on it,
            // then insert the copy in the vector
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I have tried with:

```
map<string, int> new_map = *iter1;
new_map["zero"]++;  // to avoid an infinite loop
my_vector.push_back(new_map);
```

But the program crashes. No compiler error, only a program crash.
Then I found this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255398/stl-vector-iterator-and-insert-c) in stackoverflow, so I tried another way like this:

```
int main(){
   vector<map<string, int> > my_vector;
   map<string, int> my_map;
   my_map["zero"] = 0;
   my_vector.push_back(my_map);

   int remaining = my_vector.size();
   int current_position = 0;

   while(remaining>0){
      for(map<string, int>:: iterator iter1 = my_vector[index].begin();
                                      iter1 != my_vector[index].end();
                                      iter1++){
         if(iter1->second == 0){
            map<string, int> new_map = my_vector[0];
            new_map["zero"]++;  // to avoid an infinite loop
            my_vector.push_back(new_map);
         }
      }

   index++;
   remaining = my_vector.size()-index;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But the program is still crashing, so I think the problem (or one of the problems) would be not only the iterator, but also the "copy" of the map.

If anyone have an idea of how I should do this, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: I would suggest, for clarity you should build another vector and then after coming out of the loop, append the contents of this new vector to the original vector.

Comment: Well, the problem here is only a example of the real code. The problem of doing what you say, is that the condition check and the insertion is in a recursive function. And every time I add a copy of the map, I call the same recursive function again, with the vector updated with the copy added.

Answer (score 2):

Your program may crash because `push_back` can invalidate iterators. For example if a call to `push_back` leads to memory reallocation (it happens when you exceed current `capacity` of the `vector`) then all `vector`'s iterators become invalid (they point to deallocated memory).
To solve that problem you can use indexes instead of iterators to access the `vector`'s elements or you can `push_back` new elements to another copy of the `vector`.

In other words: don't use an old `vector::iterator` after you `push_back`'ed a new element into the `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is:

```
size_t orig_size = my_vector.size();
for( size_t i = 0; i < orig_size; i++ ) {
  //...
}
```

Other way:
Build a new vector and then afterwards append the contents of this new vector to the original vector.

Answer (score 0):

I probably have the wrong idea, but I think you can do something like this. You iterate over the elements of the vector, use the predicate to see if a current element fits the criteria, then use `back_inserter`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   vector<map<string, int> > my_vector;
   map<string, int> my_map;
   my_map["zero"] = 0;
   my_vector.push_back(my_map);

   auto predicate = [](const map<string, int>& cur) {
    for (const auto& pair : cur)
    {
        if (pair.second == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
   };

   std::copy_if(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), back_inserter(my_vector), predicate);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It uses C++11 (because it looks so much better). Especially with collections C++11 gives the workflow a real boost.

```
 #include <vector>
 #include <string>
 #include <map>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std ;

 void merge(vector<map<string,int>>& from, vector<map<string,int>>& to) 
 {   
      for(auto entry : from) {
         to.push_back(entry) ;
      }   
 }   

 void search(vector<map<string,int>>& vec) 
 {   
      int iCount = 0 ; 
      vector<map<string, int>> cVector ;
      for(auto vmap : vec) {
         for(auto mapentry : vmap) {
              if(mapentry.second == 0) {
                   iCount++ ;
                   map<string, int> new_map = vmap ;
                   cVector.push_back(new_map) ;
              }   
         }   
      }   

      cout << "iCount: " << iCount << endl ;

      merge(cVector, vec) ;
 }   

 int main(){
      vector<map<string, int> > my_vector;
      map<string, int> my_map;
      my_map["zero"] = 0;
      my_map["third"] = 2 ; 
      my_map["second"] = 0 ; 
      my_vector.push_back(my_map);

      cout << my_vector.size() << endl ;

      vector<map<string,int>> cVector ;

      search(my_vector) ;

      cout << my_vector.size() << endl ;

      return 0;
 }
```

As written by Alex Antonov the `push_back` invalidates your Iterator because the memory gets reallocated. My answer creates a new vector and copies the entries after the search back in the original vector (my_vector).

About range base for-loops see [this](http://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/range-based-for/).

Comment: range base for-loop use iterators internally so I believe your example should suffer the same problem. May be you used in your program some other STL container that doesn't invalidate its iterators (e.g. `map`, `set`, `list`)?

Comment: @AlexAntonov I also thought that the range base for-loop would work internally with Iterators. I tried it with the exact same code I posted above and I don't get a segmentation fault. I am doing some Internet research about this subject (range based for-loop) right now, because I'm a little bit surprised about this too.

Comment: @AlexAntonov My initial answer was partially wrong. In the range based for-loop I don't use references, I use the dereferenced iterator (see also the link I added in my answer). If I would use a Reference (auto&) I get the initial segmentation fault again. Furthermore, when I add the element to my_vector the for-loop always runs just once in my code example above. See also [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: your example has the same problem even without using references. If you use a vector with a single element then you may be lucky. But see what happen if you have for example two elements: http://ideone.com/GVjMaQ . `iCount` is 1 but it have to be 2. When I run the same code in Visual Studio 2013 the program fires a debug assertion. The exact behavior depends on your compiler but anyhow the code is incorrect. Sometimes you may be lucky sometimes not. If I remove `push_back` the code works correct...

Comment: ... The problem is still the same 1) for-loop uses iterators, 2) `push_back` can sometimes invalidate iterators.

Comment: @AlexAntonov Thank you very much for your remarks. I've edited my answer so that it inserts into a second vector. I am still learning C++ :-)